# Angular, FormControl - confirm value change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have **form control** for selecting some value (for example - gender) and couple of `<input type="radio">`.
The requirements are next:

1. When user changes the input, I need to show a modal window which asks him to confirm or cancel  changes (without doing anything).
2. I need to show modal only if user changes input value from one gender to another.

My **problem** is that FormControl has just **valueChanges** event that emits **after** value was already changed.
And I need to set up previous value programmatically:

```
this.genderControl.setValue(GenderEnum.MALE, {emitEvent: false});
```

**Some pseudo code example:**

> component.html

```
<input
  formControlName="gender"
  type="radio"
  value="female"
  id="female"
/>
<input
  formControlName="gender"
  type="radio"
  value="male"
  id="male"
/>
<input
  formControlName="gender"
  type="radio"
  value="other"
  id="other"
/>
```

> component.ts

```
this.genderControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    startWith(null),
    pairwise(),
    takeUntil(this._destroy$)
  ).subscribe(([prev, next]: [GenderEnum, GenderEnum]) => {
    this.openWarningModal().afterClosed().subscribe((selectedAction: CommonModalsActionsEnum) => {
      if (selectedAction === CommonModalsActionsEnum.CONFIRM) {
        this.handleChangeGender(next);
      }

      if (selectedAction === CommonModalsActionsEnum.CLOSE) {
        this.genderControl.setValue(prev, {emitEvent: false});
      }
    });
  });
```

The possible **solution** may be in **removing FormControl**, using ngModel and subscription on **input click** event.
In this way on click handler shows modal and changes or doesn't change the var, related to ngModel.

But I hope that the more clear solution is exist!

Comment: Maybe on click comprare the new value with the old and in case they are deifferent open the popup

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use ngModel, instead of subscribing to the click event, you can subscribe to the

```
ngModelChanges()
```

event, which is the @Output of ngModel directive. It fires when the model changes.

Comment: It makes sense, but still believe in a clearer solution without ngModel.

Comment: If it is not much trouble, it would be helpful to find a solution if you can create a stackblitz with this.